# Separating application logic and view in Qt Widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I was wondering: what is the 'official' coding style when programming a Qt Widgets application. I'm specifically referring to keeping logic and view code separate.

The default Qt Designer way makes it very tempting to just throw everything in one class. In fact, there's a lot of code examples out there that show you can consider `MainWindow.cpp` as a 'throw all your globals in here' class.

As a simple example, your application can require a `QNetworkAccessManager`. You can store this in your `MainWindow` and then pass it to any window you open.

But this is the start of putting a whole lot of other logic in your `MainWindow`. If you then want to convert that application to QML, you have a problem. If you had created a controller class that in turn instantiates the Window or widget, or accepts the controller as constructor argument, so that you can connect view and controller with signals and slots, you would have been able to replace the view with something else, yet retain the logic. Seems a lot better to me, yet doesn't seem to be the norm.

Is it still considered bad practice to use widget/window classes (derived from `QMainWindow`, `QWidget`) for logic, even though you see it everywhere?

Comment: I agree with you, separating the logic from the view is a brilliant idea. For example if you make a calculator application, it might be tempting to put the logic in the same class as the view, but separating them would allow you to re-use the logic, or the view. The docs might be throwing people off because in the examples everything tends to be done in the same class, but the docs aren't there to teach you about programming, they are there to teach you about the Qt library, so making it compact is understandable.

Comment: As for the "official coding style", I don't think there is one. You can be sloppy and put everything in one class, but this might come back to haunt you much later. Or you could allow your application to be flexible and separate as much logic from the view as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a good idea to bring all of the code in just one class or one even one module. You would encounter many difficulties changing parts because one part is changed specially when your application becomes larger over time.

I personally use `Subdirs` to separate parts of my code (Logic, GUI). Using `Subdirs` is a good idea to separate code modules from each other. This way you can have independent software modules which are reusable and able to be changed easily. It also makes the project much cleaner and easier to read.

In this approach the modules can interact with each other through signals and slots which makes different components completely independent and changing one module does not require changing other parts.

Qt Creator provides good automation in liking the parts to each other. You can make a Subdirs project and add your subprojects to its .pro file :

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

CONFIG += ordered

SUBDIRS += \
    Component1 \
    Component2 \
    Component3 \
    MainApp \
```

You should bring the subprojects that others depend on, first in the list. Also notice that the name of the .pro file of the subproject should be the same as it's folder name. This way the subprojects are detected and listed in the Projects pane.

The subprojects `Component1`, `Component2` and `Component3` could be libraries. Part of .pro file for `Component1`:

```
TARGET = Component1
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += COMPONENT1_LIBRARY

SOURCES += ...
HEADERS += ...
```

The subproject `MainApp` can be app. Part of .pro file for `MainApp` :

```
TARGET = MainApp
TEMPLATE = app
```

You can use the libraries in each subproject by linking it to the subproject. This can be done by right clicking on the subproject and choosing `Add Library` and then `Internal Library`. When you select one library from the list of subprojects, the linking configurations are added to the .pro automatically. It will be like :

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../Component1/release/ -lComponent1
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../Component1/debug/ -lComponent1
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../Component1/ -lComponent1

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Component1
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Component1
```

Comment: But this is on a far greater scale than what I meant. My case already applies when you're making a calculator. Do you keep the array with the history of your commands as a private variable in your `MainWindow`, or do you make a controller?

Comment: Even in that simple case i think putting data structures and logic in a separate class would be beneficial. Makes your code much cleaner, easier to read and scalable.

Comment: I agree that putting logic in a separate class is better, but I'm so surprised that you see otherwise in all the code examples.

Comment: Code examples are only for showing the concept. So they are as minimal and compact as possible.

Comment: I agree with that too, but the lack of proper explaining on how it is done well contributes to people mimicking the examples. It's kind of like the same thing as synchronous vs asynchronous APIs. A lot of people make threads where you don't need to in Qt. In posts here on SO I read that that is the most common mistake by newbies. Not surprising, because I haven't really found documentation explaining the difference and what is the preferred way, with all the threading implications explained.